# ImageResizer with RemoteReader & DiskCache Plugins not showing updated remote image

Tags: asp.net-mvc, imageresizer, imageresizer-diskcache

When the remote image changes the version that is served by ImageResizer is still the old image. How is it best to work around this?

Config is pretty straight forward and as follows:

```
<diskCache dir="~/imagecache" autoClean="true" enabled="true" />
<remotereader signingKey="58h4E#O!VAiDwpYcIG!ERv74jSUs6L1!" allowAllSignedRequests="true" allowRedirects="5">
  <allow domain="domain.com" />
  <allow domain="*.domain1.com" />
  <allow domain="*.domain2.com" />
  <!-- XML whitelisting requires V3.2 or higher
  <allow domain="*.imageresizing.net" onlyWhenSigned="true"/> -->
</remotereader>
```

Answer (score 1):

RemoteReader does not wait for a round-trip HTTP request to see if an image is stale; rather, in order to provide acceptable performance, it requires that the client-facing URL be modified to perform any invalidation.

Adding *anything* to the URL, say `&imagever=2`, etc, will cause it to be re-requested and cached.

Can you invalidate a cached file without changing the URL? **No**.  Not if the backend is high-latency.

Many of our providers (excluding remotereader) allow you to enable automatic invalidation - but this always comes at too high of a performance cost. Changing the URL is the only performant solution - and frequently the *only* solution, if you have an aggressive browser or CDN involved.